# resize images by using shell script

Tags: bash

I want to resize multiple .jpg and .png images by using bash shell script.

The following script works fine, but I don't want to write same things twice.

```
for image in *.jpg; do
  mogrify -resize x1000 "${image}"
done

for image in *.png; do
  mogrify -resize x1000 "${image}"
done
```

How can I filter jpg and png images at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for image in *.jpg *.png; do
  mogrify -resize x1000 "${image}"
done
```

Comment: The only thing you might change about that is to add a `shopt -o nullglob` in front, so it doesn't put in a literal `*.jpg` or `*.png` in the loop if there are no matches for either of the expressions.